Как с grammy js создать скрипт для чека подписки и отписки на канал
Не могу понять как используя библиотеку grammy js выводить в логи к примеру user id и дату события на подписку и отписку с канала

    bot.on("chat_join_request", async (ctx) => {
        const userId = ctx.update.message.from.id;
        const username = ctx.update.message.from.username || "No Username";
        const joinDate = formattedDate(ctx.update.message.date);
      
        console.log(`New user ${username} (ID: ${userId}) has joined the channel on ${joinDate}`);
      
        try {
          await ctx.api.promoteChatMember(privateChannelId, userId, { can_post_messages: false });
          console.log(`Successfully added ${username} to the channel.`);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`Error adding user to channel: ${error}`);
          await ctx.reply('An error occurred. Please try again later.');
        }
    });


